# Where can I download a free, text-rich dataset?

Tags: database, dataset

I want to do a bit of lightweight testing and bench-marking for full-text search, so the dataset should have the qualities:

- 10,000 - 100,000 records.
- good dispersion of English words.
- In CSV or Excel format--i.e. I don't want to access it via API.

Something like books or movies with title and description fields would be perfect.  I browsed the UCI Machine Learning Repo, but it was too number-oriented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try
- [CKAN](http://www.ckan.net/)
- or [search for "Open Data"](http://www.google.com/search?q=open+dataset)

Or, [see Tim Berners-Lee discussing a quick survey of a few Open Data sets](http://www.ted.com/talks/tim_berners_lee_the_year_open_data_went_worldwide.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not find one, you can create one using the LOREM IPSUM generator

[T-SQL equivalent of =rand()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126725/t-sql-equivalent-of-rand)

You can also get the full StackOverflow data dump

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Gutenberg Project](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Main_Page). You have access to thousands of English book in plain text. That's what I've used once and was happy with it.